# How to create tags automatically on add/edit products - Shopify

Tags: shopify

I am new to shopify. I want to add a Hook (like wordpress) on product add/update where I can add/update my product's tags automatically based on type, vendor, price, weight, variant, quantity, color and more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify provides this functionality through Webhooks which can be registered by applications or through the Shopify admin dashboard.

You can find the API reference for Webhooks here:
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook